# how to wrap text in html?

Tags: jquery, html

in jquery accordion control I am displaying one image along with description.but description is coming below the image.I want to display inline with the image.
my code-

```
<div>
    <p>
    <!-- avatar -->
    <img src="images/manage.jpg" alt="" />
    <!-- /avatar -->
      Airlink's Managed Services supports a "build-operate-transfer" model, enabling service providers to quickly and cost-effectively build out a large-scale, broadband wireless network by initially outsourcing operational functions to Pronto and eventually transferring operations in-house, if desired. 
</br></p>
      As part of the service, Airlink provides all the back-office operations for customers from its Network Operations Center (NOC), leveraging its leading UniFi OSS platform.</p>
    <p>
      <a href = "#" >Read More.. </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You really should run that code through a validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="images/manage.jpg" alt="" style="float:left;" />
```

And I think, you should move image out of `<p>`

Instead of `</br>` use `<br />`

Answer (score -1):

Second way to do this:

```
<img src="images/manage.jpg" alt="" align="left" />
```

Comment: Deprecated, 1998-style of doing it. Should be avoided.